# How many Microsoft SQL Server CALs do I need for Acumatica ERP

Tags: acumatica

Is one CAL enought to operate Acumatica ERP?
Is there any "official" document containing this kind of information?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Microsoft Licensing question. According to Microsoft's [SQL Server Pricing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing#CP_StickyNav_1):

"A CAL is required for each distinct device or user to the multiplexing or pooling software or hardware front end. This remains true no matter how many tiers of hardware or software exist between the server running SQL Server and the client devices that ultimately use its data, services, or functionality."

So you would need one CAL per Acumatica user.

There is always the option of per-core licensing. Depending on the edition you are using, Microsoft has recommendations to know when it's better to use this kind of licenses. For Standard Edition, it's after 25 users, for Enterprise Edition it's for 75 users and above.